# setting java class path through php shell_exec in MAC

Tags: java, php, console

I am trying to run a java file from php through shell_exec . It works for simple jar files i.e. jar files with single class. Out of the below 2 commands the first one works fine. The second one consists of a package with two class , so to call particular class from it , I followed this calling procedure. Both the commands works fine in terminal. But the second command fails in shell_exec.

```
<?php
   echo shell_exec("java -jar First.jar hi php");
   echo shell_exec("java -cp samlePackage.jar:. samplePackage.Test");
?>
```

Here is First.class

```
class First
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println(args[0]);
      System.out.println(args[1]);
      System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

And here are the samplePackage classes

```
package samplePackage;
public class Hello
{
   public void sayHello()
   {
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}

package samplePackage;
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Hello obj = new Hello();
       obj.sayHello();
   }
}
```

I am not able to figure out my mistake. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo shell_exec("java -cp samlePackage.jar:. samplePackage.Test");` Do you mean `samplePackage.jar` ?

Comment: I have made jar file from the classes using the command :

     jar cmf Manifest.txt samplePackage.jar samplePackage

Manifest.txt contains : Main-Class: Test